# Cant get Qualcomm ath10k rev32 to work

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless

so I have been trying to get a linux distro working on my samsung tab pro s, which is running the newest release of ubuntu, The hardware is a QCA6174 (rev32), At first the whole setup ran with a few errors, but wifi wouldnt work, then i tried [this](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=208874), when it didnt work i tried going back to the old installed firmware and just setting that hw3.0 directory to execute with chmod, and now i have some new errors and it still doesnt work, here is the importaint part from kern.log:

```
Sep  9 21:15:20 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S kernel: [    3.562223] ath10k_pci 
0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/pre-cal-pci-0000:01:00.0.bin 
failed with error -2
Sep  9 21:15:20 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S kernel: [    3.562234] ath10k_pci 
0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:01:00.0.bin 
failed with error -2
Sep  9 21:15:20 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S kernel: [    3.563043] ath10k_pci 
0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-5.bin 
failed with error -2
Sep  9 21:15:20 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S kernel: [    3.563045] ath10k_pci 
0000:01:00.0: could not fetch firmware file 'ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-
5.bin': -2
Sep  9 21:15:20 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S kernel: [    3.563543] input: HID 
04e8:a00a as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-
5:1.2/0003:04E8:A00A.0004/input/input10
Sep  9 21:15:20 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S kernel: [    3.564941] ath10k_pci 
0000:01:00.0: qca6174 hw3.2 target 0x05030000 chip_id 0x00340aff sub 
144d:c135
Sep  9 21:15:20 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S kernel: [    3.564943] ath10k_pci 
0000:01:00.0: kconfig debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 1 dfs 0 testmode 0
Sep  9 21:15:20 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S kernel: [    3.565596] ath10k_pci 
0000:01:00.0: firmware ver WLAN.RM.2.0-00180-QCARMSWPZ-1 api 4 features 
wowlan,ignore-otp,no-4addr-pad crc32 75dee6c5
Sep  9 21:15:20 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S kernel: [    3.623617] hid-generic 
0003:04E8:A00A.0004: input,hiddev0,hidraw1: USB HID v1.12 Device [HID 
04e8:a00a] on usb-0000:00:14.0-5/input2
Sep  9 21:15:20 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S kernel: [    3.632489] ath10k_pci 
0000:01:00.0: failed to fetch board data for 
bus=pci,vendor=168c,device=003e,subsystem-vendor=144d,subsystem-device=c135 
from ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/board-2.bin
Sep  9 21:15:20 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S kernel: [    3.632707] ath10k_pci 
0000:01:00.0: board_file api 1 bmi_id N/A crc32 ed5f849a
Sep  9 21:15:20 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S kernel: [    3.635919] dw-apb-uart.6: 
ttyS4 at MMIO 0xdf643000 (irq = 20, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A
Sep  9 21:15:20 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S kernel: [    3.832846] [drm] RC6 on
Sep  9 21:15:20 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S kernel: [    4.544637] input: 
SYNP1234:00 06CB:5810 as 
/devices/pci0000:00/INT3446:00/i2c_designware.0/i2c-5/i2c-
SYNP1234:00/0018:06CB:5810.0001/input/input11
Sep  9 21:15:20 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S kernel: [    4.544791] hid-multitouch 
0018:06CB:5810.0001: input,hidraw2: I2C HID v1.00 Device [SYNP1234:00 
06CB:5810] on i2c-SYNP1234:00
Sep  9 21:15:20 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S kernel: [    4.553958] hid-multitouch 
0003:04E8:A00A.0002: failed to fetch feature 8
Sep  9 21:15:20 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S kernel: [    4.562480] hid-multitouch 
0003:04E8:A00A.0002: failed to fetch feature 8
Sep  9 21:15:20 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S kernel: [    4.571406] input: HID 
04e8:a00a Touchpad as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-
5:1.0/0003:04E8:A00A.0002/input/input17
Sep  9 21:15:20 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S kernel: [    4.571588] hid-multitouch 
0003:04E8:A00A.0002: input,hiddev0,hidraw3: USB HID v1.12 Mouse [HID 
04e8:a00a] on usb-0000:00:14.0-5/input0
Sep  9 21:15:20 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S kernel: [    4.798748] audit: type=1400 
audit(1505013320.242:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" 
profile="unconfined" name="content-hub-clipboard" pid=716 
comm="apparmor_parser"
Sep  9 21:15:20 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S kernel: [    4.798752] audit: type=1400 
audit(1505013320.242:3): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" 
profile="unconfined" name="content-hub-peer-picker" pid=717 
comm="apparmor_parser"
Sep  9 21:15:20 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S kernel: [    4.802430] audit: type=1400 
audit(1505013320.246:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" 
profile="unconfined" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=719 comm="apparmor_parser"
Sep  9 21:15:20 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S kernel: [    4.802433] audit: type=1400 
audit(1505013320.246:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" 
profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" 
pid=719 comm="apparmor_parser"
Sep  9 21:15:20 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S kernel: [    4.802435] audit: type=1400 
audit(1505013320.246:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" 
profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-helper" pid=719 
comm="apparmor_parser"
Sep  9 21:15:20 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S kernel: [    4.802438] audit: type=1400 
audit(1505013320.246:7): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" 
profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=719 
comm="apparmor_parser"
Sep  9 21:15:20 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S kernel: [    4.802674] audit: type=1400 
audit(1505013320.246:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" 
profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session" pid=718 
comm="apparmor_parser"
Sep  9 21:15:20 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S kernel: [    4.802677] audit: type=1400 
audit(1505013320.246:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" 
profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session//chromium" 
pid=718 comm="apparmor_parser"
Sep  9 21:15:20 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S kernel: [    4.803428] audit: type=1400 
audit(1505013320.246:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" 
profile="unconfined" name="url-dispatcher-bad-url-helper" pid=720 
comm="apparmor_parser"
Sep  9 21:15:20 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S kernel: [    4.892964] Bluetooth: BNEP 
(Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
Sep  9 21:15:20 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S kernel: [    4.892966] Bluetooth: BNEP 
filters: protocol multicast
Sep  9 21:15:20 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S kernel: [    4.892970] Bluetooth: BNEP 
socket layer initialized
Sep  9 21:15:20 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S NetworkManager[787]: <info>  
[1505013320.5652] init!
Sep  9 21:15:20 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S NetworkManager[787]: <info>  
[1505013320.5654] management mode: unmanaged
Sep  9 21:15:20 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S NetworkManager[787]: <info>  
[1505013320.5656] devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/lo, iface: 
lo)
Sep  9 21:15:20 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S NetworkManager[787]: <info>  
[1505013320.5656] device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/lo, iface: 
lo): no ifupdown configuration found.
Sep  9 21:15:20 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S NetworkManager[787]: <info>  
[1505013320.5656] end _init.
Sep  9 21:15:20 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S NetworkManager[787]: <info>  
[1505013320.5657] settings: loaded plugin ifupdown: (C) 2008 Canonical Ltd.  
To report bugs please use the NetworkManager mailing list. (/usr/lib/x86_64-
linux-gnu/NetworkManager/libnm-settings-plugin-ifupdown.so)
Sep  9 21:15:20 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S NetworkManager[787]: <info>  
[1505013320.5657] settings: loaded plugin keyfile: (c) 2007 - 2015 Red Hat, 
Inc.  To report bugs please use the NetworkManager mailing list.
Sep  9 21:15:20 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S NetworkManager[787]: <info>  
[1505013320.5657] (247531648) ... get_connections.
Sep  9 21:15:20 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S NetworkManager[787]: <info>  
[1505013320.5657] (247531648) ... get_connections (managed=false): return 
empty list.
Sep  9 21:15:20 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S NetworkManager[787]: <info>  
[1505013320.5894] keyfile: new connection /etc/NetworkManager/system-
connections/Cisco3869 (db31d28c-fcff-40c9-88e3-c7e41b487965,"Cisco3869")
Sep  9 21:15:20 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S NetworkManager[787]: <info>  
[1505013320.6144] keyfile: new connection /etc/NetworkManager/system-
connections/You Cant Handle The WIFI (01971c31-af26-4141-a819-
9ad6d2a3a39a,"You Cant Handle The WIFI")
Sep  9 21:15:20 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S NetworkManager[787]: <info>  
[1505013320.6358] keyfile: new connection /etc/NetworkManager/system-
connections/You Cant Handle The WIFI 1 (01c4bfea-d257-49d5-8951-
e9b7607eec2a,"You Cant Handle The WIFI 1")
Sep  9 21:15:20 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S NetworkManager[787]: <info>  
[1505013320.6389] get unmanaged devices count: 0
Sep  9 21:15:20 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S NetworkManager[787]: <info>  
[1505013320.6921] settings: hostname: using hostnamed
Sep  9 21:15:20 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S NetworkManager[787]: <info>  
[1505013320.6921] settings: hostname changed from (none) to "jlee-Galaxy-
TabPro-S"
Sep  9 21:15:20 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S NetworkManager[787]: <info>  
[1505013320.6924] dhcp-init: Using DHCP client 'dhclient'
Sep  9 21:15:20 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S NetworkManager[787]: <info>  
[1505013320.6924] manager: WiFi enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by 
state file
Sep  9 21:15:20 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S NetworkManager[787]: <info>  
[1505013320.6924] manager: WWAN enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by 
state file
Sep  9 21:15:20 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S NetworkManager[787]: <info>  
[1505013320.6925] manager: Networking is enabled by state file
Sep  9 21:15:20 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S NetworkManager[787]: <info>  
[1505013320.6925] Loaded device plugin: NMVxlanFactory (internal)
Sep  9 21:15:20 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S NetworkManager[787]: <info>  
[1505013320.6925] Loaded device plugin: NMVlanFactory (internal)
Sep  9 21:15:20 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S NetworkManager[787]: <info>  
[1505013320.6926] Loaded device plugin: NMVethFactory (internal)
Sep  9 21:15:20 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S NetworkManager[787]: <info>  
[1505013320.6926] Loaded device plugin: NMTunFactory (internal) 
Sep  9 21:15:20 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S NetworkManager[787]: <info>  
[1505013320.6927] Loaded device plugin: NMMacvlanFactory (internal)
Sep  9 21:15:20 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S NetworkManager[787]: <info>  
[1505013320.6927] Loaded device plugin: NMIPTunnelFactory (internal)
Sep  9 21:15:20 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S NetworkManager[787]: <info>  
[1505013320.6927] Loaded device plugin: NMInfinibandFactory (internal)
Sep  9 21:15:20 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S NetworkManager[787]: <info>  
[1505013320.6927] Loaded device plugin: NMEthernetFactory (internal)
Sep  9 21:15:20 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S NetworkManager[787]: <info>  
[1505013320.6928] Loaded device plugin: NMBridgeFactory (internal)
Sep  9 21:15:20 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S NetworkManager[787]: <info>  
[1505013320.6928] Loaded device plugin: NMBondFactory (internal)
Sep  9 21:15:20 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S NetworkManager[787]: <info>  
[1505013320.6999] Loaded device plugin: NMBluezManager (/usr/lib/x86_64-
linux-gnu/NetworkManager/libnm-device-plugin-bluetooth.so)
Sep  9 21:15:20 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S NetworkManager[787]: <info>  
[1505013320.7003] Loaded device plugin: NMAtmManager (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-
gnu/NetworkManager/libnm-device-plugin-adsl.so)
Sep  9 21:15:20 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S NetworkManager[787]: <info>  [ 
1505013320.7006] Loaded device plugin: NMWwanFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-
gnu/NetworkManager/libnm-device-plugin-wwan.so)
Sep  9 21:15:20 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S NetworkManager[787]: <info>  
[1505013320.7010] Loaded device plugin: NMWifiFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-
linux-gnu/NetworkManager/libnm-device-plugin-wifi.so)  
Sep  9 21:15:20 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S NetworkManager[787]: ((devices/nm-
device.c:970)): assertion '<dropped>' failed
Sep  9 21:15:20 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S NetworkManager[787]: <info>  
[1505013320.7069] device (lo): link connected
Sep  9 21:15:20 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S NetworkManager[787]: <info>  
[1505013320.7080] manager: (lo): new Generic device 
(/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/0)
Sep  9 21:15:20 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S NetworkManager[787]: <info>     
[1505013320.7087] manager: startup complete
Sep  9 21:15:20 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S NetworkManager[787]: <info>  
[1505013320.7183] urfkill disappeared from the bus
Sep  9 21:15:20 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S NetworkManager[787]: <info>  
[1505013320.7195] ModemManager available in the bus
Sep  9 21:15:20 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S NetworkManager[787]: <info>  
[1505013320.7200] bluez: use BlueZ version 5
Sep  9 21:15:21 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S indicator-sound[1133]: volume-control-
pulse.vala:735: unable to get pulse unix socket: 
GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name 
org.PulseAudio1 was not provided by any .service files
Sep  9 21:15:21 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S indicator-keybo[1128]: 
gtk_icon_theme_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
Sep  9 21:15:22 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S kernel: [    6.875482] Bluetooth: 
RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
Sep  9 21:15:22 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S kernel: [    6.875489] Bluetooth: 
RFCOMM socket layer initialized
Sep  9 21:15:22 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S kernel: [    6.875493] Bluetooth: 
RFCOMM ver 1.11
Sep  9 21:15:24 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S kernel: [    8.952671] ath10k_pci   
0000:01:00.0: failed to ping firmware: -110
Sep  9 21:15:24 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S kernel: [    8.952686] ath10k_pci   
0000:01:00.0: failed to reset rx filter: -110
Sep  9 21:15:24 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S kernel: [    9.038718] ath10k_pci 
0000:01:00.0: could not init core (-110)
Sep  9 21:15:24 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S kernel: [    9.038784] ath10k_pci 
0000:01:00.0: could not probe fw (-110)
Sep  9 21:15:26 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S indicator-keybo[1540]: Couldn't connect 
to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-uZJu6g5y29: 
Connection refused
Sep  9 21:15:26 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S bamfdaemon[1495]: Couldn't connect to 
accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-uZJu6g5y29: 
Connection refused
Sep  9 21:15:26 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S indicator-sound[1501]: volume-control-
pulse.vala:735: unable to get pulse unix socket: 
GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name 
org.PulseAudio1 was not provided by any .service files
Sep  9 21:15:26 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S indicator-print[1526]: Couldn't connect   
to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-uZJu6g5y29: 
Connection refused
Sep  9 21:15:26 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S unity-settings-[1519]: Couldn't connect 
to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-uZJu6g5y29: 
Connection refused
Sep  9 21:15:26 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S gnome-screensav[1556]: Couldn't connect 
to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-uZJu6g5y29: 
Connection refused
Sep  9 21:15:26 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S gnome-screensav[1556]: Couldn't get 
presence status: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any 
.service files
Sep  9 21:15:26 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S gnome-session-c[1637]: Couldn't connect 
to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-uZJu6g5y29: 
Connection refused
Sep  9 21:15:26 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S unity-panel-ser[1666]: Couldn't connect 
to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-uZJu6g5y29: 
Connection refused
Sep  9 21:15:26 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S unity-settings-[1519]: Unable to 
register client: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The 
name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files
Sep  9 21:15:26 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S indicator-datet[1494]: Unrecognized 
TZID: 'Etc/Utc'
Sep  9 21:15:26 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S indicator-datet[1494]: Unrecognized 
TZID: 'Etc/Utc'
Sep  9 21:15:27 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S unity-settings-[1519]: Failed to load 
PNP ids: Failed to open file “/usr/share/hwdata/pnp.ids”: No such file or 
directory
Sep  9 21:15:27 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S colord[1183]: failed to get session 
[pid 1519]: No such device or address  
Sep  9 21:15:27 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S unity-settings-[1690]: Name taken or 
bus went away - shutting down
Sep  9 21:15:27 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S unity-settings-[1519]: Failed to load 
PNP ids: Failed to open file “/usr/share/hwdata/pnp.ids”: No such file or 
directory
Sep  9 21:15:27 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S unity-settings-[1519]: Failed to load 
PNP ids: Failed to open file “/usr/share/hwdata/pnp.ids”: No such file or 
directory
Sep  9 21:15:27 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S indicator-appli[1734]: Unable to get 
watcher name 'org.kde.StatusNotifierWatcher'
Sep  9 21:15:27 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S indicator-appli[1734]: Name Lost
Sep  9 21:15:27 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S gnome-session-binary[1554]: Entering 
running state
Sep  9 21:15:27 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S at-spi2-registr[1721]: Failed to 
register client: GDBus.Error:org.gnome.SessionManager.AlreadyRegistered: 
Unable to register client
Sep  9 21:15:27 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S at-spi2-registr[1721]: Unable to 
register client with session manager
Sep  9 21:15:28 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S fwupd[1860]: disabling plugin because: 
failed to startup dell: Firmware updating not supported
Sep  9 21:15:28 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S fwupd[1860]: disabling plugin because: 
failed to coldplug raspberrypi: Raspberry PI firmware updating not 
supported, no /boot/start.elf  
Sep  9 21:15:28 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S fwupd[1860]: disabling plugin because: 
failed to coldplug synapticsmst: MST firmware updating not supported by OEM
Sep  9 21:15:29 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S unity-panel-ser[1666]: 
window_menu_model_new: assertion 'BAMF_IS_APPLICATION(app)' failed
Sep  9 21:15:29 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S unity-panel-ser[1666]: track_menus: 
assertion 'IS_WINDOW_MENU(menus)' failed
Sep  9 21:15:29 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S unity-panel-ser[1666]: 
window_menu_model_new: assertion 'BAMF_IS_APPLICATION(app)' failed
Sep  9 21:15:29 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S unity-panel-ser[1666]: track_menus: 
assertion 'IS_WINDOW_MENU(menus)' failed
Sep  9 21:15:29 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S gnome-screensav[1556]: Lost the name, 
shutting down.
Sep  9 21:15:30 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S NetworkManager[787]: <info>  
[1505013330.4815] manager: WiFi hardware radio set enabled
Sep  9 21:15:30 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S NetworkManager[787]: <info>  
[1505013330.4816] manager: WWAN hardware radio set enabled 
Sep  9 21:15:42 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S unity-scope-loa[1905]: daemon.vala:144: 
Failed to load Software Center index. 'Apps Available for Download' will not 
be listed
Sep  9 21:15:42 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S zeitgeist-datah[1932]: Attempting to   
read the recently used resources file at '/home/jlee/.local/share/recently-
used.xbel', but the parser failed: Failed to open file 
“/home/jlee/.local/share/recently-used.xbel”: Permission denied.
Sep  9 21:15:43 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S unity-panel-ser[1666]: 
window_menu_model_new: assertion 'BAMF_IS_APPLICATION(app)' failed
Sep  9 21:15:43 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S unity-panel-ser[1666]: track_menus: 
assertion 'IS_WINDOW_MENU(menus)' failed
Sep  9 21:15:47 jlee-Galaxy-TabPro-S zeitgeist-datah[1988]: zeitgeist-
datahub.vala:227: Unable to get name "org.gnome.zeitgeist.datahub" on the  
bus!
```

I have tried nearly every other solution for this but nothing seems to work, i have tried different distros like debian, and centos, and have tried to get everything to work, on the deceive i do not have an internet connection, there is no ethernet, my netgear dongles dont work with linux, and i know just enough of linux to be dangerous. I could really use some help.

edit:

[here are the network diagnostics](http://paste.ubuntu.com/25506682/)

Comment: added the network diagnostics

Comment: Did you install the `linux-firmware` package? (Reboot your computer or unload and reload the `ath10k_pci` kernel module after the firmware installation).

Comment: i ran sudo apt-get install linux-firmware and it says it is already the newest version, i dont know how to reload a firmware though.

Comment: alright i found a thing on modprobe and ran sudo modprobe -r ath10k_pci and sudo modprobe ath10k_pci, and nothing came up with either of them

Comment: Could you please try to upgrade the package with https://packages.ubuntu.com/artful/all/linux-firmware/download? If that doesn't work you can also get the newest published firmware as described at https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/ath10k/firmware.

Comment: I installed that firmware package then rebooted and ran dmesg ath10k there were more errors and it seems to be looking for  hw3.0/firmware-5.bin